# Store object instances of PCA9635 in array

Tags: c++, arrays, object, arduino, i2c

I am working with a hardware PWM-LED-Controler called "PCA9635". This chip can be controlled in Arduino with the Library "[PCA9635](https://github.com/RobTillaart/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/PCA9635)".

In the example provided in the library, an ledArray with the i2c address 0x70 is initiated by:

```
#include "PCA9635.h"

PCA9632 ledArray(0x70);
```

My Project requieres an unknown number of PCA935 controllers to be controlled with a different address each.

How can i create an array like:

```
PCA9635 ledControlers[2] = {0x70,0x71};
```

The above does not work. Error Message from the compiler:
`conversion from 'const int' to non-scalar type 'PCA9635' requested`

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
PCA9635 ledControlers[2] = {PCA9635(0x70), PCA9635(0x71)};
```

or

```
PCA9635 ledControlers[] = {PCA9635(0x70), PCA9635(0x71)};
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. Could you explain the logic too?

Comment: https://www.includehelp.com/cpp-tutorial/array-of-objects-initialization-with-constructors-in-cpp.aspx shows "how to initialize array of objects using constructors in C++". BTW: Question is independent of I2C and rather C++ than Arduino specific.

Comment: @matchless_clueless when you use `PCA9635 ledControlers[2] = {0x70,0x71};`  you are assigning const int to object of type PCA9635. When you use `PCA9635 ledControlers[2] = {PCA9635(0x70), PCA9635(0x71)};` you are assigning object created using constructor of PCA9635 to object that is of type PCA9635 .